# How to dry-up similar Doctrine functions from two Entity Repositories?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I'm using Symfony 4.

```
namespace App\Repository;

use ...

class CountryRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Country::class);
    }

    ...

    public function deleteMultipleByIds(array $ids): void
    {
        $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder('l');
        $builder->delete()
            ->where('l.id IN(:ids)')
            ->setParameter(
                ':ids',
                $ids,
                Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY
            );

        $query = $builder->getQuery();
        $query->execute();
    }
```

Same method exists in `CountryI18nRepository` class.

I'd want there to be just one function like that, which will just use correct Entity (Country v CountryI18n).

How and where do I create a new class? Should that class be of `ServiceEntitiyRepository` class or otherwise which?

Comment: Instead of making your own base repository class, you could probably implement this with a trait.  Have not tried this specific use case myself but I don't see why it would not work.

Comment: Clean way to do this is to use services and composition over inheritance. See [How to use Repository with Doctrine as Service in Symfony](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/10/16/how-to-use-repository-with-doctrine-as-service-in-symfony)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is about duplication, you can make a `GenericRepo` (not necessarily a doctrine repository; please choose a better name) that you can inject and use where you need.

Something like

```
class GenericRepo
{
  public function deleteMultipleByIds(QueryBuilder $qb, string $rootAlias, array $ids): void
  {
    $qb->delete()
      ->where(sprintf('%s.id IN(:ids)', $rootAlias))
      ->setParameter(':ids', $ids, Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY);

    $qb->getQuery()->execute();
  }
}
```

And in your, for instance `CountryI18nRepository`

```
class CountryI18nRepository
{
  private $genericRepo;

  public function __construct(GenericRepo $genericRepo)
  {
    $this->genericRepo = $genericRepo;
  }

  public function deleteMultipleByIds(array $ids): void
  {
    $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder('l');

    $this-> genericRepo->deleteMultipleByIds($builder, 'l', $ids);
  }
}
```

You could also extend from `GenericRepo` but, since PHP only supports single inheritance, is better (at least in my opinion) to use the composition as shown above.

### Disclaimer

I didn't tested this code so it is possible that some adjustment will needed. Concepts shown btw are valid.

Comment: This is a much better solution as it's decoupled from Symfony and Doctrine. I extend such an approach in a post [How to use Repository with Doctrine as Service in Symfony](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/10/16/how-to-use-repository-with-doctrine-as-service-in-symfony/)

Answer (score 1):

create an abstract repository with the deleteMultipleByIds like :

```
abstract class BaseCountryRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
```

and extend it instead of ServiceEntityRepository in the other CountryRepositories

```
class CountryRepository extends BaseCountryRepository

class CountryI18nRepository extends BaseCountryRepository
```

you can remove the deleteMultipleByIds definition from these classes

Comment: Beware of such solutions that will eventually lead to inheritance hell. Why? See [When to declare classes final](https://ocramius.github.io/blog/when-to-declare-classes-final/)

Comment: is this why you down voted?! try to provide a solution instead, if you work with symfony you will know that this approach will work fine without any drawbacks

Comment: @TomášVotruba: I would agree that this is a perfectly valid use case for inheritance. One parent class, one intermediate class and two implementation classes sharing code. Where’s the problem in this particular case?

Comment: @lxg In my experience of consulting over 50 PHP project the "it's ok just here" approach leads to big legacy issues, that are such pain to decouple, that it's worth it to write the application from scratch. The problem is, one class is never a problem. The consequences in the next 5 years of such a decision are.  See the refered post. Most of "WHYs" are there.

Comment: @AbdelhafidElKadiri I linked solution in the rest of the comments. See [How to use Repository with Doctrine as Service in Symfony](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/10/16/how-to-use-repository-with-doctrine-as-service-in-symfony).

Not everything that works is correct. Moreover in framework vendor lock, be careful about that.